# List users by Year of Birth using a foreach loop to dynamically populate years and data

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, users

I have a custom meta_key called "date_of_birth"

i am trying to create a table of user counts for each year based on that value.

I have this code to count by specific year and also to calculate the age for over under test:

```
    $usercount = get_users(array('meta_key' => 'date_of_birth', 'meta_value' => 
    '1991', 'count_total' => true, 'meta_compare' => 'LIKE'));

    //count how many were born in 1991
    $countfor1991= count($users);

    //get age for over under test
    $birthday = $user->date_of_birth; 
    $age = date_diff(date_create($birthday), date_create('today'))->y;
```

what i need is some kind of loop that gets all the users with metakey "date_of_birth" and then cycles through each year to create the following chart:

```
YEAR TOTAL OVER18 UNDER18
2017   5     3      2
2016   2     1      1
ETC... so on .. so forth
```

But i need the table to be dynamic so that next year it will add the current year of 2018 to the beginning and continue on...

I thought maybe a WP_Query would work, but i can't figure out the right code for that one either.

Answer (score 0):

So, I solved this by doing a regular get_user() and putting it inside a for loop of years and ran the get_user on each year.

```
$currentYear = date('Y');
$years = range($currentYear, 1900);

foreach($years as $year){

    $TotalArray = get_users(array('meta_key' => 'date_of_birth', 'meta_value' => $year, 'count_total' => true, 'meta_compare' => 'LIKE', 'role__in' => 'members'));
    $thisYearsTotal = count($TotalArray);

//echo some <tr> and <td> html for formatting.  

}
```